# The LDAP server is unavailable

Tags: c#, asp.net, ldap

I'm a total newbie to this

Trying to connect to an ldap server with `PrincipalContext`. I have tried all solutions on this site to no avail.

Things I've tried:

```
PrincipalContext insPrincipalContext = 
   new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

PrincipalContext insPrincipalContext = 
   new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "ldap://localhost:389/dc=maxcrc,dc=com");

PrincipalContext insPrincipalContext = 
   new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "maxcrc.com");
```

All give the same result:

> *LDAP server not available*

Only `ContextType.Machine` works basically.

Not sure if my LDAP server is set up correctly:

- Host: localhost
- Port: 389
- Base DN: dc=maxcrc,dc=com
- URL: ldap://localhost:389/dc=maxcrc,dc=com

Testing with Softerra LDAP Browser

Any tutorials from start to finish will be much appreciated...

Comment: This might sound stupid, but try `LDAP://` instead of `ldap://` as I know it's fixed connections for me in the past

Comment: no still same result. but thanks

Comment: Can you connect to the LDAP server using any standard AD tools?

Comment: @mellamokb if by standard AD tools you mean DirectoryEntry then yes. i've tried: DirectoryEntry rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE");

Answer (score 15):

I have been facing the same issue and I found a solution.

I'm able to connect easily using following code:

```
 ADUser_Id = "domainName\\username"; //make sure user name has domain name.
 Password = "xxxx";
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"server_address", ADUser_Id,Password);
/* server_address = "192.168.15.36"; //don't include ldap in url */
```

Comment: Specifying the server host name worked for me.  I was able to use the user without the domain for `ADUser_Id`.  Good post.

Answer (score 5):

I had similar issues. It turned out that I had to pass username and password in the object initialization. Please try using a statement like below:

```
PrincipalContext insPrincipalContext = 
new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, 
"ldap://localhost:389/dc=maxcrc,dc=com",
userName,
password);
```

Also make sure that your username has domain in it.

For example,

```
userName = "mydomainname" + "\\" + "john_jacobs"
```

Comment: For me it worked passing the credentials directly into the object initialization as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following constructor overload for `PrincipalContext`:

```
public PrincipalContext(
    ContextType contextType,
    string name,
    string container
)
```

And separate the server name from the LDAP string:

```
PrincipalContext insPrincipalContext = 
   new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "localhost:389", "dc=maxcrc,dc=com");
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348316%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In my environment I had to create the principal context with just the domain controller host name, and then separately validate the user credentials.

```
string domainControllerName = "PDC";
string domainName = "MyDomain"; // leave out the .Local, this is just to use as the prefix for the username if the user left it off or didn't use the principal address notation
string username = "TestUser";
string password = "password";

using (var ldap = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainControllerName))
{
    var usernameToValidate = username;
    if (!usernameToValidate.Any(c => c == '@' || c == '\\'))
            usernameToValidate = $"{domainName}\\{username}";

    if (!ldap.ValidateCredentials(username, context.Password, ContextOptions.SimpleBind))
        throw new UnauthorizedException();
}
```

> This example allows for all three of these variations to the username to validate:
>
> - TestUser
> - MyDomain\TestUser
> - TestUser@MyDomain.Local

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try your local machine address instead :

```
ldap://127.0.0.1:389/dc=maxcrc,dc=com
```

If that doesn't work, I'd fire up Wireshark, and have it capture traffic on port 389 as you're attempting to connect via Softerra.

In my time working with LDAP and .Net DirectoryServices, that error usually means the syntax or naming convention of the path is incorrect, or does not point to a valid directory end point.

Answer (score 0):

That error might be due to trying to connect as "Anonymous" without specifying it explicitly.
By default all connections are Negotiable. So if you try something like that you could try the following:

```cs
LdapDirectoryIdentifier ldap = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("My Hostname or IP Address",10389); //10389 might be your non default port
LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(ldap);
connection.AuthType = AuthType.Anonymous;
```